# Using apple watch + nike + running without the phone

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I have seen this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188407/do-you-still-need-iphone-when-running-with-apple-watch) and there generally very little information  on this topic. In the question linked above the they talk about the activity app. I use nike+ running. Last time I went for a run I ran for some time with my phone in my pocket, then I ran without it and the watch would not pick up the distance or any other info during the run. I started the run from my watch so I thought it should not be problem. Has anyone figure this one out yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Apple's included Workout app can record activity and heart-rate data without the iPhone, but the Nike+ Running app can't (as of the 17<sup>th</sup> of November 2015).

Here's the info page from the iPhone Nike+ Running app (*Nike+ Running > Settings > Apple Watch*)..

[image: Screenshot of Nike Running app (v4.8.3) on iPhone]

Nike state that you need to have your iPhone on you.

Comment: that is pretty sad, hope apple guys are going to allow more access to developers in the near future. thanks for your answer

Comment: I hope so too. Apple recently provided a way [to sync and play music from the Watch to bluetooth headphones](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204691) and the example they give is a 'Workout Playlist' so they're adding capabilities a bit at a time  :o)